# Better performance of filling ListBox DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, listbox, datatemplate

I've got an `ListBox` that has an `DataTemplate`. This `DataTemplate` is filled in CodeBehind but the performance is really bad. The method that fills it is called in the constructor. Please tell me how I can improve it

```
 <ListBox  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                  Name="lbCars"
                                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="100"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Height="auto" Width="125" Source="{Binding car_img_src}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Text="ID:" FontSize="12"  FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2" />
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Text="Name:"  Margin="0, 0, 0, 2"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Kategorie:"  FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Tuning:"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding car_id}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding car_name}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding car_group}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding car_tuning}"/>
                                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

And now how I fill it:

```
        public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeRsc();
    }
```

InitializeRsc:

```
carList.Add(new carEntry { car_id = 400, car_group = "Off Road", car_img_src = "Resources/cars/Vehicle_400.jpg", car_name = "Landstalker", car_tuning = "Transfender" }); 
... ((about 300-500 others))
```

I fill 4 ListBoxes with about 100-200 items each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the problems I see:

1. Your ListBox is in fact not virtualized. Setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` disables virtualization regardless of other properties you set. Changing it to `True` should fix this.
2. There's no need to use `VirtualizingStackPanel` in your `ItemTemplate`. The virtualization won't come into play since you have only 4 TextBlocks in each panel, and you're just adding a needless overhead. Use `StackPanel` instead.

Comment: ContentScroll is disabled cause of the ugly empty white space that would apppear below the entries. I'll number 2

Comment: You will see the greatest performance benefit by fixing #1. If I were you I'd set `CanContentScroll` to `True` and see how I can fix the other issue caused by it.